Error: Cannot Read Properties of Undefined (Reading 'databaseName') in NestJS Paginate with TypeORM Relations
I'm working on a NestJS project where I'm using nestjs-paginate with TypeORM. I have a Customer entity that has PhoneNumber and Dealer as related entities, and I’m trying to paginate Customer records along with these relations.
Here's my Customer entity:
@Entity()
export class Customer extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @OneToOne(() => PhoneNumber, { cascade: true, nullable: true, onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
    @JoinColumn()
    phoneNumber?: PhoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne(() => Dealer, { cascade: true, nullable: true, onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
    @JoinColumn()
    dealer?: Dealer;
}

In the CustomerService, I have the following findAll function for pagination:
async findAll(query: PaginateQuery): Promise<Paginated<Customer>> {
    return paginate(query, this.customerRepository, {
        sortableColumns: ['id', 'name', 'tc_no', 'email'],
        relations: ['dealer', 'phoneNumber'],
        nullSort: 'last',
        defaultSortBy: [['id', 'DESC']],
        searchableColumns: ['name', 'tc_no', 'email', 'address'],
        select: [
            'id', 'name', 'tc_no', 'phoneNumber', 'address', 'email', 'dealer', 'created', 'updated', 'deleted'
        ],
        filterableColumns: {
            name: [FilterOperator.EQ, FilterSuffix.NOT],
            email: [FilterOperator.EQ],
            tc_no: [FilterOperator.EQ],
            deleted: [FilterOperator.EQ],
        },
    });
}

When running this code, I'm encountering the following error:
[Nest] ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'databaseName')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'databaseName')
at  /typeorm/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts:3685:41

add your paginate method
